# Foreach, add class to each three

Tags: php

Im having some PHP problems. I have a array that I display with `foreach`
The code looks like this:

```
foreach($names as $key => $name):

echo $name;

endforeach;
```

Lets say there are 6 names, then it would output this:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
Name6
```

Now the thing I need is to group three names in a div. Like this

```
<div class="group">
Name1
Name2
Name3
</div>
<div class="group">
Name4
Name5
Name6
</div>
```

But I actually have no idea how to do this, I've tried a few things that didn't work.

What is the best way to structure this?

Thanks in advance! Let me know if there was something unclear that I need to explain better.

Comment: What have you actually tried? Seems straightforward to open a <div>, output 3 names in your loop, close <div>, repeat as needed.

Comment: You could just put the names into a 2D array as groups  so GROUP1{n1,n2,n3} GROUP2{n1,n2,n3}  Call the array Groups :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = 1;
foreach($names as $key => $name):
if$count == 1)
{
echo '<div class="group">';
}

echo $name;
$count++;
if($count == 3)
{
echo '</div>';
$count = 1;

}

endforeach;
```

I hate counting in a foreach but it seems like the easiest solution, maybe a for loop where it is already being counted would be better suited.

Comment: this actually won't close the the last div if there is only one name left in the array

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution:

```
$names=array("peter", "tom", "felix", "patrick", "paul", "sam", "bill");

foreach($names as $key => $name){
    //if the key is 0 we just started and have to open a div
    if($key==0){
        echo '<div class="group">';
    }

    //actually echo the name in our div
    echo $name;

    //if the key can be divided by 3 we have to close our div
    //we add one because index starts with 0
    $close=is_int(($key+1)/3);

    //and we want to close the div if there is no more element in our array
    if(!array_key_exists($key+1, $names)){
       $close=true;
    }


    if($close){
        //close the div 
        echo '</div>';
        //if there is another element in our array we have to open the tags again
        if(array_key_exists($key+1, $names)){
            echo '<div class="group">';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div class="group">'
$index = 0;

foreach($names as $key => $name):

echo $name;
$index++;
if($index%3==0)
{
echo '</div>'
echo '<div class="group">'
}
endforeach;
echo '</div>'
```